# Highcharts: too much space for bottom legend

Tags: highcharts

I am new to Highcharts, but I feel it is so powerful and like it very much.

I am doing a multiple series chart. Here is what I have for the legend:

```
legend: {
    enabled: true,
    verticalAlign: 'bottom',
    align:'center',
}
```

But I got too much space above and below the legend. See the picture. How can I reduce it?

[image]

**Update**
It seems I can use positive y value in

```
legend { y: number }
```

to move legend down, but I cannot seem to be able to reduce the space above the legend. I tried padding and margin without any success.

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`chart.marginBottom`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.marginBottom) instead

```
 chart: {            
            marginBottom: 60
        }
```

[@jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/3g8pnep2/) to demonstrate margin between chart and legends

If real estate is a concern, also evaluate the option of the [making the legends floating](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.floating)

Comment: Jugal, your solution plus twist on legend such as  legend: {
  itemMarginBottom: 5,
  itemMarginTop: 5,
  padding: 0,
  y:20
} works great. Thanks so much for showing this property!!